# Should I use a property to access a base class global variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I have a class structure like this:

```
public class PingtreeReq : ProviderRequest
{
    // I want to use _residentialService here!
}

public class ProviderRequest
{
    // Should this be a variable or property?
    protected Dictionary<int, string> _residentialSerice;
}
```

If I want to use this varable from MyLenderRequest, is it more appropriate to use a property or is accessing it like this as a protected varable adequate?

Comment: you mean you have a public field `_residentialStatus` in `ProviderRequest` ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta - from the question i deduce _residentialStatus is `private` at the moment and OP wonders if he should make it `protected` or have a (`protected`) property for it. Btw. I'd use a property and inside `ProviderRequest` change every call to `_residentialStatus` that does not absolutely need to use the variable directly to use that property. And then I'd probably change it to an auto-property if there is no place left that uses the variable directly.

Comment: What is "global variable" in context of C#? Post the `_residentialStatus` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use it externally make it a public property, if you are only going to use it in inheriting classes make it a protected property.

```
public class ProviderRequest
{
    protected Dictionary<int, string> ResidentialService { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Even when used internally by the class in which it is defined, I would use the property and not the field directly.

Comment: @Bernard - agreed. If it's just a simple property which only returns the value, then *maybe*. But then again, why not make it `{ get; private set; }`. And if you ever want to add some logic to the property you have parts of the code that use it and parts that don't, which doesn't help predictability.

Comment: Yes, I agree. In his case he talked about a field, and instead of making the field externally available I would add a property to expose the field.

Answer (score 3):

`_residentialStatus` is more like a private variable, which is private to the class. You can add a protected property in `ProviderRequest` that encapsulates the private variable and use that in `ProviderRequest`.